# separate git commit/pull request

Tags: git

I originally cloned a repository from master and made changes. I was told to make three separate branches that would each have their own relative commits and pull requests. 
After I was finished with the changes I had made, I did the follow steps 3 times for the 3 branches:

```
//For branch one
1) git checkout -b branchOne
2) git add file1 file2 file3
3) git commit -m "commit msg"
4) git push --set-upstream origin [branch_name]

//For branch two
1) git checkout -b branchOne
2) git add file4 file5 file6
3) git commit -m "commit msg"
4) git push --set-upstream origin [branch_name]
```

After doing this three times, it created 3 branches but they all shared the same commit history. The commit histories were basically being updated/appended to the next branch.

WHAT I NEED TO DO NOW:

NOW I need to separate these commits so that each branch that is already made will have its own pull requests and relative commits.
How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:
On top of this, I also need to add new commits to some of the branches as well. 
So in summary, I need to separate the commits into their own branches (the ones that already exist) as well as add additional new commits to the branches.

How can I revert the commits I have already made and then commit them only to the relative branches.

Comment: It sounds like you checked out branches consecutively from each new branch you created. Before doing `git checkout -b` you should have done a `git checkout master` to branch the next branch off of master instead of off your newly created branch with new changes.

Comment: are you trying to say `file1` should be on one branch, `file2` should be on another and `file3` should be on 3rd branch? It's hard to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @ArunG I have updated my post

Comment: "How can I revert the commits I have already made and then commit" 
Why are you trying to revert the commits?

Comment: Well I thought I would revert the commits and then commit again properly so that each branch could have their own relative commits.

Comment: @Henry Lee Did you do `git checkout -b branchOne` for creating second branch also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [interactive](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) [rebase](https://billtheconqueror.com/2018/07/24/commit-early-commit-often-the-interactive-rebase-delete/).

1. `git checkout branchTwo`
2. `git rebase -i origin/master`
3. In the editor that appears, delete the line(s) (commits) that should NOT be on `branchTwo`
4. Save and exit the editor
5. Look at your version tree using something like `gitk` or `git log` to verify that `branchTwo` looks correct.
6. Push `branchTwo` to origin, `git push -f origin branchTwo:feature/branchTwo` (the `-f` flag is a `force push` and should be used only if the branch you are pushing to is fully within your control.  You *probably* would not want to do this on a branch that is shared by other developers.).

Repeat the above steps for each branch that you want to un-tangle.  Note, this will only work if the commits in `branchTwo` are not dependent on the commits in `branchOne` (for example if they share files that are changed on conflicting lines).

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: How do I save and exit the editor after I remove a commit?

Comment: @HenryLee, it depends on what editor you are using.  If it is vi, `:x` will save and close the editor.  To just save without closing, `:w`.  If it is not vi, you'll have to lookup how to save the document for whatever editor it is.  Note, you can configure git to use an editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `git log`to take a look at your commit history and look for the commit right before your changes. Remember the first 4-6 digits of the hash. While you are at it, also write down the first letters of your 3 commit hashes.
2. `git checkout <hash prior to your changes>` - Your repository is now at the last clean commit without your changes.
3. Create and checkout your feature branch from here: `git checkout -b feature/feature01`.
4. `git cherry-pick <hash of first feature commit>` - This moves this commit's changes in your current branch.

You now have these changes on your new branch, exclusively. Repeat starting from step 2 for each feature.

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding to the question.

> **Q:** it created 3 branches but they all shared the same commit history

Means you are branching off every time from the new branch you have created. So that must have end up this way.

```
master    - - - -
                 \
branchone         -  
                   \
branchtwo           -
                     \
branchthree           -
```

If you are only one working on the branches you can perform a rebase on the branches with master.

**Below is the process of rebasing:**

First `branchtwo`

`git rebase --onto master branchtwo branchone`

Means branchtwo will be rebased onto master from branch one

do same with `branchthree`

`git rebase --onto master branchthree branchtwo`

**This will change into below representation:**

```
             / * - branchtwo
master - - - * - branchone
             \ * - branchthree
```